# Output a Latin Square

Tags: code-golf, array, matrix

An \$n\times n\$ [Latin Square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square) is a grid containing exactly \$n\$ distinct values where the values in each row and column are distinct. For example,

$$\begin{matrix}
A & B & C \\
C & A & B \\
B & C & A \\
\end{matrix}$$

is a Latin square as no row or column contains a repeated value.

You are to take a positive integer \$n\$ as input and output an \$n\times n\$ Latin Square. The values can be any \$n\$ distinct values, and do not have to be consistent for different \$n\$. Your program should be consistent and deterministic, so running it with the same input should always produce the same output.

You may output in any reasonable manner, including a flat array consisting of \$n^2\$ values, or as a list of \$n\$ lists, each containing \$n\$ values. You may input and output in any [convenient method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

<sub>These are just some possible outputs, your program may differ so long as the output is correct</sub>

```
1 [[1]]
2 [[1, 2], [2, 1]]
3 [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2]]
4 [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 1, 4, 3], [3, 4, 1, 2], [4, 3, 2, 1]]
5 [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 5, 1, 4], [3, 5, 4, 2, 1], [4, 1, 2, 5, 3], [5, 4, 1, 3, 2]]
```

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/186356/66833). [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/79676/66833). Brownie points for beating or matching my 12 byte Jelly answer

Comment: It there an upper limit on `n` the code can assume?

Comment: @cnamejj Yeah, you'll never have to handle an integer greater than the square root of the maximum integer in your languages (basically, don't worry about big `n` so long as your algorithm is sound)

Answer (score 18):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 37 bytes

Outputs a flattened \$ n \times n \$ latin square.

```python
lambda n:((range(n)*-~n)[1:]*n)[::~n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcuxCsIwGATgPU9xYxIrWAeHH/okNUOkjf6g1xK6uPTVY0IHlzs4vlu/22vhtaThXt7x85giKNbmyOds6fx5pxt7Cb6WyM5Q0pJBKHGYvsPNiUHMGQNS/Rg0on9y6UDPGs1hzcqt8VFFTwzmWMoP)

Comment: Very nice! I'll post a bounty when the question becomes eligible.

Comment: @xnor Thanks, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 12):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
RṙⱮ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/o4c6Zjzau@3@43f3/f2MA)

### Explanation

```
RṙⱮ  Monadic link, takes an argument z
R    [1, 2, ..., z-1, z]
  Ɱ  For each on right argument (z, defaults to loop over range)
 ṙ   Rotate the left list by the right amount
```

Alternative solution: `+þ%`. Generates the \$n\times n\$ addition table and then applies modulo to bring the elements into range.

Comment: First time I've seen caird coinheringaahing get beaten that bad.

Comment: beat me to it lol

Comment: rip the 12 byte answer

Comment: The advantage of 3 byte answers is that they are easy to bruteforce. :)

Comment: @EricDuminil I wouldn't say 16.7 million is _that_ easy, but I guess it's all subjective, especially since it's not like there's particularly a good way to determine if a 3-byte sequence is a valid solution.

Comment: @hyper-neutrino: Sorry, I didn't want to downplay your impressive achievement. I should have written "possible" instead of "easy".

Comment: @EricDuminil Oh, no worries, I didn't feel like you were trying to do that, and honestly, I wouldn't even say this answer is particularly impressive, at least for someone with experience in Jelly. It's definitely possible though - at least, a couple of users here a while back brute-forced every valid 2-byte Jelly program (since some are invalid), so it's definitely a feasible idea!

Answer (score 11):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 30 bytes

```r
n=scan();outer(1:n,1:n,`+`)%%n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8@2ODkxT0PTOr@0JLVIw9AqTweEE7QTNFVV8/6b/gcA)

Answer (score 10):

## [APL (dzaima/APL)](https://github.com/dzaima/APL), 4 bytes

```apl
⌽ᐵ⍨⍳
```

```apl
⌽ rotate
ᐵ each left, apply each left element to the entire right argument
⍨ apply to both arguments
⍳ range
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pSszMTfz/P@1R24RHPXsfTtj6qHfFo97NXI/6pgKF0hRM4SyT//8B)

Comment: Ok, that's really cool. I've not come across ᐵ before.

Comment: @AndrewOgden yeah it's dzaima/APL specific, equivalent in regular dyalog would have to use rank (or ⊂ like bubbler's solution)

Answer (score 10):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

```
⍳⌽,⍨⍴⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1Hv5kc9e3Ue9a541LsFyPmf9qhtwqPevkddzYfWGz9qm/iob2pwkDOQDPHwDP6fpmACAA)

There's already a nice [4-byter in dzaima/APL](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223592/78410) by rak1507, but I wanted to share a non-trivial short one in vanilla Dyalog. It is shorter than a modulo addition table `⊢|⍳∘.+⍳` and ties with the trivial port of rak's `⍳⌽¨∘⊂⍳`.

Takes n and creates a flat matrix of numbers.

```
⍳⌽,⍨⍴⍳   ⍝ Input: n
  ,⍨     ⍝ [n, n]
    ⍴⍳   ⍝ Reshape [1..n] into an n×n matrix
         ⍝ For n = 4, this looks like this:
         ⍝ 1 2 3 4
         ⍝ 1 2 3 4
         ⍝ 1 2 3 4
         ⍝ 1 2 3 4
⍳⌽       ⍝ Rotate first row once, second row twice, ..., n-th row n times
         ⍝ 2 3 4 1
         ⍝ 3 4 1 2
         ⍝ 4 1 2 3
         ⍝ 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 32 bytes

```hs
f n=[[x..n]++[1..x-1]|x<-[1..n]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hzzY6ukJPLy9WWzvaUE@vQtcwtqbCRhfEzouN/Z@bmJmnYKuQm1jgq6ABJguKMvNKFPQU0jQVQIpMY/8DAA)

A kind-of boring approach, just concatenates the ranges.

**34 bytes**

```hs
f n=[mod(k+div(-k)n)n|k<-[1..n*n]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hzzY6Nz9FI1s7JbNMQzdbM08zrybbRjfaUE8vTysvNvZ/bmJmnoKtQm5iga9CQVFmXomCCoijkKYAUmMa@x8A)

Outputs a flat list, zero-indexed, using the method from [my Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223604/20260). A slight adaptation is needing to make it work for `[1..n*n]` instead of `[0..n*n-1]`.

Answer (score 6):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 7 bytes

```
|i.+/i.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/azL1tPUz9f5rcqUmZ@QrpCkYQhjqurrqMCHT/wA)

Creates an "addition table" of the range 0..n with itself `i.+/i.` and then takes the mod of each element by n `|`.

Answer (score 6):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 19 bytes

```
!n=((N=1:n).+N').%n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/XzHPVkPDz9bQKk9TT9tPXVNPNe9/SmZxQU5ipYaioaZ1QVFmXklOnoYmF1zUCKuoKVZRQwMk4f8A)

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 23 bytes

```
+##&~Array~{#,#}~Mod~#&
```

or (as @Roman suggested)

```
Plus~Array~{#,#}~Mod~#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277X1tZWa3OsagosbKuWllHubbONz@lTlntf0BRZl6Jgr5DerRp7P//AA)

-2 bytes thanks to @att

Comment: [23 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277X1tZWa3OsagosbKuWllHubbONz@lTlntf0BRZl6Jgr5DerRp7P//AA)

Comment: `Plus~Array~{#,#}~Mod~#&` has the same count and is less cryptic.

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>37</s> 35 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Delfad0r
Would have saved 5 bytes thanks to @AZTECCO (see [xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223609/95792))

```hs
f n=[mod(x+o)n|x<-[1..n],o<-[1..n]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hzzY6Nz9Fo0I7XzOvpsJGN9pQTy8vVicfxor9n5uYmadgZaXg6a@gockF5tkqFBRl5pUoqCjkJhYopCmAlJrG/gcA)

Comment: [-2 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hzzY6Nz9Fo0I7XzOvpsJGN9pQTy8vVicfxor9n5uYmadgZaXg6a@gockF5tkq5CYW@MYraBQUZeaVKOgppGkqgJSbxv4HAA "Haskell – Try It Online") if you output a flat list.

Comment: Using mod is a good idea but you can just concat two sequences around 'o' for [32](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hzzY6Ol9PLy9WWzvaUE8vX9cwtibfRhfEzouN/Z@bmJmnYGWl4OmvoKHJBebZKhQUZeaVKKgo5CYWKKQpgJSaxv4HAA "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: @AZTECCO Thanks! I see xnor posted the same answer (after you suggested your tip), so I think I'll go back to Delfad0r's solution so it isn't the same.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 40 bytes

```python
lambda n:[(k+k/n)%n for k in range(n*n)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKlojWztbP09TNU8hLb9IIVshM0@hKDEvPVUjTytPM/Y/SDAPIWioY6ZpVVCUmVeikKaRp/kfAA)

Since the challenge allows a flat list of `n*n` outputs, we make do mapping `k=0, 1, ... n*n-1` to the corresponding entry with `(k+k/n)%n`. We can get this by adding the row index `k/n` and column `k%n` and reducing modulo `n`, and removing the redundant inner `%n`. We could also do `k*-~n/n%n`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 22 bytes

```
.+
*
Y`\_`w
L$`.
$<'$`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X0@bS4srMiEmPqGcy0clQY9LxUZdJeH/fxMA) Explanation:

```
.+
*
```

Convert the input to unary.

```
Y`\_`w
```

Take the first `n` word characters (or use `p` for printable ASCII etc.)

```
L$`.
$<'$`
```

Create cycled rows. (`$<'` is the same as `$&$'`.)

Answer (score 5):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 21 bytes

```matlab
@(n,x=1:n)mod(x+x',n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQSNPp8LW0CpPMzc/RaNCu0JdJ0/zf2JesYal5n8A)

The same thing as many other answers...

-2 bytes by [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe)

Answer (score 5):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io/), 33 bytes

```
$[n][map 0..(n*n)-1'x[(x+x/n)%n]]
```

[Try it on the Arturo Playground!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?HMWlRd) **Note: it seems that editing the code edits it for everyone, so don't do that.**

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-a`, 34 bytes

```perl
$,=$";say$_.."@F",1..$_-1for 1..$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19Fx1ZFybo4sVIlXk9PycFNScdQT08lXtcwLb9IAcz8/9/kX35BSWZ@XvF/XV9TPQNDg/@6iQA)

Answer (score 5):

## [yuno (abandoned)](https://github.com/hyper-neutrino/yuno-abandoned/), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/hyper-neutrino/yuno-abandoned/wiki/Byte-count)

```
ップア＠％
```

### Explanation

```
ップ　　　　outer product table; for each (first) and for each (second)
　　ア　　　add
　　　＠　　swap top two
　　　　％　modulo
```

Can be written as `ppua@%`. Code is grouped as `[ップ][ア][＠][％]`. To prove this is actually 4 bytes, the bytecode is `'~\x00ðó'` (use the `b` flag to interpret code from bytecode).

Answer (score 5):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 20 bytes

```
range(.*.)*(1+1/.)%.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/78oMS89VUNPS09TS8NQ21BfT1NV7/9/EwA)

output is flattened

(my first jq answer)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 46 bytes

```javascript
n=>[...Array(n)].map((_,i,a)=>a.map(_=>i++%n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LclBCoNADEDRq8ymmKDN1lUGeo4qEqzKiE0kiuDpp0Xcvc@f5ZCt97TuT7XPkEfOyvFNRC93OUGxpa@sAF2VKkGOcmXHMZXlQxFzb7rZMtBiE4xQ4/U9cAxOsyWFIhSINxv9O/8A)

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 42 bytes

As pointed out by [@tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44718/tsh), returning a flatten array is shorter.

```javascript
n=>[...Array(n*n)].map((_,i)=>(i/n+i)%n|0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcvbCoJAEADQX/FFnEmbTQp8WsHvCJFlvTSiM7JKENW3b533M7un233g7TiL9kMcbRRb34moCcG9QE6CLa1uA@gKRlsDG8kZU/lcMHqVXZeBFp1ghAppVhbIkgz/5fAPMPQur0V5@5oJMf4A)

Comment: use flatten matrix is shorter `n=>[...Array(n*n)].map((_,i)=>(i/n+i%n)%n|0)`

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 43 bytes

```python
lambda x,r=range:[r(i,x)+r(i)for i in r(x)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaFCp8i2KDEvPdUqukgjU6dCUxtIaablFylkKmTmKRRpVGjG/i8oyswrUUjTMNTkgjGNEExjBNMEwTTV/A8A)

Answer (score 4):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <sup><s>73</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>49</s></sup> 46 bytes

Saved 3 bytes thanks to [dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88546/dingledooper)!!!

```c
a;f(n){for(a=n*n;a;)printf("%d ",--a*~n/n%n);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3BCoMwEETv@YolIGy0ofTSy9aPWVIigp2KWnqQ9NObBpXOZdiZt0zwYVB0OatEhlvjc2JtUUNU3Dj1WCLb6k725L3WH5xRwUnKD@3BzqyGisoTcUEJ1NJFit3oKtQ0cFu/UxtZNuR/ja9lZmuPJJlk8jfEQbs5@/cP)

Inputs \$n\$ and prints the Latin Square as a flat array consisting of \$n^2\$ values.

Comment: [46 bytes](https://tio.run/##PY3BCoMwEETv@YolIGy0ofTSy9aPWVIigp2KWnqQ9NObBpXOZdiZt0zwYVB0OatEhlvjc2JtUUNU3Dj1WCLb6k725L3WH5xRwUnKD@3BzqyGisoTcUEJ1NJFit3oKtQ0cFu/UxtZNuR/ja9lZmuPJJlk8jfEQbs5@/cP) by iterating backwards and using a shorter formula which outputs negatives instead.

Comment: @dingledooper Nice one with negatives - most ingenious, thanks! :D

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-m`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 3 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Output as a 2D array.

```
WéU
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW0&code=V%2blV&input=NAotUQ)

Or without the `-m` flag:

### [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ÆZéX
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=xlrpWA&input=NAotUQ)

Comment: Ok I can understand the 4bytes one but the 3bytes?OMG!

Comment: @AZTECCO, probably the best kept secret in Japt!

Comment: Realistically both are 4 bytes though, one just moves one byte into the flag.

Comment: @Etheryte, [flags don't count towards our scores](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/).

Comment: @Downvoter, what's the problem?

Comment: @Shaggy I'm well aware of that meta post, I don't think it's a reasonable interpretation though. I could make a copy of Japt where the whole code is taken as flags, doesn't mean that the code size is 0 bytes.

Comment: It does but we also have a consensus against that, via MetaGolfScript. If you strongly believe we _should_ include flags in our scores then the place to argue that point and try to change the consensus back is in the meta post.

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 3 bytes

```
5YL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3zTS5/9/CwA)

```
          %implicit input n
5YL       % create circular matrix of size n
```

Equivalent to the following Octave/MATLAB code

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 23 bytes

```matlab
@(n)gallery('circul',n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z@mYKugp6f330EjTzM9MScntahSQz05syi5NEddJ0/zf5qGpeZ/AA)

Alternately, this is equivalent to [tsh's Octave answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223622/67312).

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 5 bytes

```matlab
:&+G\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/30pN2z3m/39TAA)

```matlab
	% implicit input n
:	% range 1:n
&+	% add to itself transposed, with broadcast
G\	% push n and modulo n
	% implicit output
```

Answer (score 3):

## Scala, 44 bytes

```scala
n=>1 to n flatMap(_=>1 to n)sliding n take n
```

[Try it in Scastie!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/EZzhiRjVQgOTdOfyHL2c5Q)

This is so simple it hardly needs an explanation, but here's one anyway:

```scala
n =>                     //The input
1 to n                   //Make a range of n numbers
  flatMap(_ => 1 to n)   //Map each to the range [1, n] and flatten
                         //This creates a list of n*n numbers
  sliding n              //Take n-sized chunks and move ahead by one each time
  take n                 //Keep the first n chunks
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
LD._
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fx0Uv/v9/UwA)

```
LD._  # full program
  ._  # push...
L     # [1, 2, 3, ...,
      # ..., implicit input...
L     # ]...
  ._  # rotated to the left...
      # (implicit) each element in...
LD    # [1, 2, 3, ...,
      # ..., implicit input...
LD    # ]
      # implicit output
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
o £o éX
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=byCjbyDpWA&input=NC1S)

```
o   - [0..U)
£   - map by:
o éX    > rotate X times [0..U)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 61 bytes

```powershell
param($n)(0..($n*$n-1)|%{[math]::floor($_+$_/$n)%$n})-join" "
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVPU8NATw9Ia6nk6Rpq1qhWR@cmlmTEWlml5eTnF2moxGurxOsDlamq5NVq6mblZ@YpKSj9///fCAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <sup><s>38</s></sup> 30 bytes

```
"aD@aO0<ESC>V{g<C-A>V}JqqYpdw$pq@a@qdk
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/XynRxSHR38DGNdjZLqw63cZZ19EurNarsDCyIKVcpaDQIdGhMCX7/39jg/@6ZQA)

Input as a single number.

Range creating script taken from Leo's [Range, Reverse, Sum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223249/80214) answer.

-8 bytes from Leo using `J`.

Fixed the problem with multidigit numbers.

### Explanation

```
"aD@aO0<ESC>V{g<C-A>V}J
"aD                          delete first line and store in register a
   @aO0<ESC>                 print 0 on a newline a times
            V{g<C-A>         convert the zeroes to a range
                    V}J      select all, join with spaces

$xqqYp2x$pq@a@qdk
$x                           remove the last space
  qq                         start macro q:
    Yp                        duplicate current line
      dw                      remove first word (number + space)
        $p                    paste at the end
          q                  end macro
           @a@q              replay macro a times
               dk            delete last two extra iterations
```

Comment: You can select everything and use `J` to join lines with spaces more efficiently [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/XynRxSHR38DGNdjZLqw63cZZ19EurNarsDCywKhCpaDQIdGhMCX7/3/j/7plAA "V (vim) – Try It Online")

Comment: ah, yes. I'll add it in.

Comment: Your answer (and my golf) don't work properly for multidigit input though

Comment: lmao, I need to delete a word instead

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 33 bytes

```
->n{(0..n*n-1).map{|x|(x+x/n)%n}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfqGCr8F/XLq9aw0BPL08rT9dQUy83saC6pqJGo0K7Qj9PUzWvtvZ/gUKiXnJiTo6CMRecafofAA)

A lambda proc returning a flat array of n*n elements.

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 56 bytes

```java
n->{for(int i=n*n;i-->0;)System.out.println((i/n+i)%n);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jU09T8MwEN3zK54qIcWNYrqwYNKFiYGpI2IwblJdSM6Rfa6Eqvz24JaPhQ4Mp6d7n7092rrfvy80Tj4I@vzrJDTotSn@cF1iJ@T5LLrBxohnS4xTAUzpbSCHKFYyHD3tMWat3EkgPry8woZDVBcr8MTy6DmmsQ3omoXr7anzoSQWUMNrNlTX241Ru48o7ah9Ej3lGhm4LOmWK1I3rMy8mEtbjuIriwYbk@GhwV3GqvoZBK5UUbW6Xynzbei0da6dpKRf6krmH9pcnG9ePgE)

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 79 bytes

```python
n=input()
f=lambda b:f(b+b[-1:]+b[-n:-1])if len(b)<n*n else b
print f(range(n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcWxDkAwEAbg3VPceEcMJJaGJxFDL1qa1K@hBk9f8S1fevN@oi8FU0B6Mkvlp2gPXS2p8ayNzm1nlj@YtlskeIoOrDKiBrl4O9IqXQGZPF8Wm2OIlDJ8)

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! Be sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python) page for ways you can golf your program. This doesn't currently output the answer with a `print ` before the `f` so you should add that to your score: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcWxDkAwEAbg3VPceEcMJJaGJxFDL1qa1K@hBk9f8S1fevN@oi8FU0B6Mkvlp2gPXS2p8ayNzm1nlj@YtlskeIoOrDKiBrl4O9IqXQGZPF8Wm2OIlDJ8 "Python 2 – Try It Online"). (cont).

Comment: (cont). Alternatively, you could change it into a version that's just a function (so doesn't need the `range` when calling, so that you only have to count the function definition

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Edited. I had been testing in the REPL, hence the lack of a `print`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `r`, 4 bytes

```
ƛ⁰ɾǔ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=r&code=%C6%9B%E2%81%B0%C9%BE%C7%94&inputs=5&header=&footer=)

```
ƛ      for each in [1, ..., N]
 ⁰     push N
  ɾ    pop N, push [1, ..., N]
   ǔ   rotate
```

-1 byte thanks to Aaron Miller

Comment: You can rotate ranges now

Comment: @lyxal poggers.

Comment: [4 bytes](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=r&code=%C6%9B%E2%81%B0%C9%BE%C7%94&inputs=5&header=&footer=)

Comment: @AaronMiller oh, nice, i thought i tried that, lol

Answer (score 3):

## [yuno (abandoned)](https://github.com/hyper-neutrino/yuno-abandoned/), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/hyper-neutrino/yuno-abandoned/wiki/Byte-count)

```
メリョ
```

(Disclaimer - rotate was implemented after this challenge, and I'm not sure about map. However, neither of these nor the way empty-stack is treated were designed with this challenge in mind, it just turns out that the way I want my functions to work supports this challenge more nicely than Jelly)

(`リョ` is one byte)

By abusing the way I manage my stack, we can get this down to two bytes, which is pretty much the minimum possible unless you either have a latin square built-in for some reason, or a "rotate by each in range" built-in.

```
メ　　  For each element in the second-from-top-of-stack
　リョ  Rotate Left
```

If the stack's size is insufficient, popping will give the first command line argument instead. If that doesn't exist, it will input each time. Thus, you can make this rectangular by using STDIN. Otherwise, supply the number as a command line argument, and it'll use that value for the TOS and second-TOS.

Thus, for each `x` in `1, ..., N`, it rotates `N` to the left by `x`, and rotating a number casts it to a range by default.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3 - <s>127</s> 118 bytes

```python
n=int(input())
m,o=[],[]
for i in range(n):
  m.append(i)
for i in range(n):
  o.append(m)
  m=m[-1:]+m[:-1]
print(o)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc07CgIxEADQfk4xZQY3QrQL5CQhxYKrTjEfQixy@sgWdvYPns/xNr1Hnz7X0sI6Aqt/RiAC2azUttUGT@vIyIp919cRlDIgynV3P/QRmP4D@wGhkxepMeV2kZpjauD9zIxgrXT7Ag)

Simple answer - takes a contiguous subset of numbers, cycles it every row, and prints (aka, the usual formula).

Comment: You can easily golf ~30 bytes off just by removing all the spaces around the `=`, `+` and `+=` commands

Comment: Fails for inputs >223.

Comment: This is 115 bytes, but you can make it [104 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P882M69EIzOvoLREQ1OTK9c231ZJiSstv0ghUyEzT6EoMS89VSNP0ypX2zY5o0jD2Fg7UxOLdL62ba62UkyeknWubW60rmGsdm60FZDiKigCmZ@v@f@/KQA)

Comment: @Makonede Let me see what I can do about that.

Comment: @Makonede Fixed now.

Comment: @StackMeter Your bytecount is wrong and your program is invalid (outputs spaces between numbers).

Comment: @Makonede 1) Sorry - I don't know how to count bytes. 2) That's the point (how else would you separate the numbers).

Comment: @StackMeter First of all, your answer contains no non-ASCII characters, meaning 1 char=1 byte for your entire program. Second, [your output is wrong](https://tio.run/##dc0xDoMwDEDRPaewPMUyHVDFguSTUIYOLfVgOwrp0NMHOECnvzzpl1/7hN97d1FvWb18WyZKNoQgDojpHRUU1KE@fXtlpzkBGMvealZihD8kWIzx4XhxseU2rmzLfCaVer2Cep8O); not only is it shifted weird, but it also outputs the wrong numbers. Please always **test your program** and **link to an online interpreter** before posting.

Comment: @Makonede I think this time it's fixed (with a link this time).

Comment: @StackMeter Please link to the actual program, not just the place you paste it in. And why PyPy instead of CPython?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123060/discussion-between-stackmeter-and-makonede).

Comment: You can save a few bytes by indenting one space instead of two.

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <sup>45</sup> 44 bytes

```bash
for((i=0;i<$1*$1;)){
echo $[(i/$1+i++)%$1]
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifpqFZ/T8tv0hDI9PWwDrTRsVQS8XQWlOzmis1OSNfQSVaI1NfxVA7U1tbU1XFMJar9n8tV5qCIURWXR3INv4PAA)

<sup>-1 thanks to dingledooper</sup>

Prints flattened square, one element per line.

Comment: [44 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifpqFZ/T8tv0hDI9PWwDrTRsVQS8XQWlOzmis1OSNfQSVaI1NfxVA7U1tbU1XFMJar9n8tV5qCIURWXR3INv4PAA)

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, 36 bytes

```
=MOD(SEQUENCE(A1)+SEQUENCE(1,A1),A1)
```

This seems to be similar to some of the solutions in other languages.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 12 bytes

```
ＮθＩＥθ⁺…ιθ…⁰ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05oroCgzr0TDObG4RMM3sUCjUEchIKe0WCMoMS89VSNTR6FQU0cBwjHQUcjUBAHr//9N/@uW5QAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Note that Charcoal's default output doesn't look much like an array. Other 12-byte variants are possible, e.g. modular arithmetic between range and row number or modular sum of row and column. Explanation: Simply concatenates the ranges from `i` to `n` and from `0` to `i` for every row.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 5 bytes

```
.>LUQ
```

[Test suite](http://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=.%3ELUQ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5&debug=0)

Explanation:

```
.>LUQ  | Full program
.>LUQQ | with implicit variables
-------+----------------------------------
.>LUQ  | rotate range(input) right d times
  L  Q | for each d in range(input)
```

Python 3 translation:

```
Q = eval(input())

print(list(map(lambda d: list(range(Q)[-d:])+list(range(Q)[:-d]), range(Q))))
```

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, 28 bytes

```
Prompt N
For(I,1,N
Disp remainder(I+seq(J,J,1,N),N
End
```

Outputs each row as a list on a separate line. Note that `remainder(` only works for TI-84+/SE with the 2.53 MP OS. The below version uses 2 more bytes but is compatible with earlier OS's.

#### 30 bytes

```
Prompt N
For(I,1,N
Disp NfPart((I+seq(J,J,1,N))/N
End
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>43</s> 41 bytes

Saved 2 byte thanks to [caird coinheringaahing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66833/caird-coinheringaahing)!!!

```python
lambda n:[(a+a//n)%n for a in range(n*n)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rcg9DkBAEAbQ3immETt@gugkXATFCIuEb2WjEXH2ReWVbz@P2aBwumrdKls/CKFslESSpmAfpI0loQVkBdOoEII79yX@zOM849Kj124XHEoHF25Karq0At8Buwc)

Port of my [C answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223608/9481) (turns out to be the same as [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor)'s [Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223604/66833)).

Comment: You can remove the `f=`, and [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223604/66833) is a duplicate answer in Python 2

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Duh, so used to writing recursively forgot! T_T Not a duplicate since I didn't copy it and the variable names are different! :P

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 35 bytes

```sh
n=$1
repeat n\*n echo $[a++*~n/n%n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/z1bFkKsotSA1sUQhL0YrTyE1OSNfQSU6UVtbqy5PP081L/b///@mAA)

Port of @dingledooper's golf to @Noodle9's [C answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223608), but in reverse.

The `\` is a work-around for a bug in `zsh`, and could be removed in a later version for -1.

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), 64 bytes

```
&::01-v_@
99+*77<^\-*86g99`+1\*:\-*86g99:::.%\+-*86g99/\-*86g99p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//9Xs7IyMNQti3fgsrTU1jI3t4mL0dWyMEu3tEzQNozRsoLxrKys9FRjtKE8fZhwwf//JnoA)

This is my first Befunge answer, so I'm sure it can golfed a lot more. I'm particularly frustrated about the repetition of `99g68*-`, which is the best way I could store an extra counter, since I couldn't find an equivalent of Factor/Forth's `2dup` or `rot` for Befunge, nor can I define a function.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 30 bytes

```ruby
->n{w=*1..n;w.map{w=w.rotate}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vutxWy1BPL8@6XC83sQDIK9cryi9JLEmtrf1foJAWbRzLBaJMY/8DAA)

A little late, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

## MMIX, 56 bytes (14 instrs)

Stores a flattened \$n\times n\$ Latin square into second argument.
The pattern is:

```
5 4 3 2 1
1 5 4 3 2
2 1 5 4 3
3 2 1 5 4
4 3 2 1 5
```

Declaration:

```
void __mmixware latinsq(wyde n, wyde *storage);
```

(jxd -T)

```
00000000: c1020000 c1030000 c1040000 a7020100  Ḋ£¡¡Ḋ¤¡¡Ḋ¥¡¡ʂ£¢¡
00000010: e7010002 27030301 73ff0301 220202ff  ḃ¢¡£'¤¤¢s”¤¢"££”
00000020: 260404ff 27020201 62030300 62020200  &¥¥”'££¢b¤¤¡b££¡
00000030: 5b04fff7 f8000000                    [¥”ẋẏ¡¡¡
```

```
latinsq SET  $2,$0          // i = n
        SET  $3,$0          // j = n
        SET  $4,$0          // k = n
0H      STWU $2,$1,0
        INCL $1,2           // loop: *storage++ = i
        SUBU $3,$3,1
        ZSZ  $255,$3,1      // t = !--j
        ADDU $2,$2,$255     // i += t
        SUBU $4,$4,$255     // k -= t
        SUBU $2,$2,1        // i--
        CSZ  $3,$3,$0       // if(!j) j = n
        CSZ  $2,$2,$0       // if(!i) i = n
        PBNZ $4,0B          // iflikely(k) goto loop
        POP  0,0            // return
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Risky](https://github.com/Radvylf/risky), 21 bytes

```
00?+0*_?-1/_?-1+_0+02-0?+0+_]+]+_]+]+_]+]
```

[Try it online!](https://radvylf.github.io/risky?p=WyIwMD8rMCpfPy0xL18_LTErXzArMDItMD8rMCtfXStdK19dK10rX10rXSIsIls2XSIsMF0)

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 67 bytes

```go
import."fmt"
func f(n int){
for k:=0;k<n*n;k++{Println((k+k/n)%n)}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BmoLE5OzE9FSF3MTMvKWlJWm6FjedM3ML8otK9JTSckuUuNJK85IV0jTyFDLzSjSrudLyixSyrWwNrLNt8rTyrLO1tasDioBSOXkaGtna2fp5mqp5mrW1EKM2gTWDjNbQVKhO0zDVhEosWAChAQ)

Outputs each element of the flattened square on a newline.

Answer (score 0):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/)/[MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab.html), 21 bytes

with the help of the built-in function [`magic`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/magic.html)

> M = magic(n) returns an n-by-n matrix constructed from the integers 1 through n^2 with equal row and column sums. The order n must be a scalar greater than or equal to 3 in order to create a valid magic square.

---

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6enF/PfQSNPMzc/RSM3MT0zGcjWydPUNvxvzZWWX6SQZ2toZWhlysWZkllcoJEGlNW0hnKUYvKUgJzUvJT/AA)

```matlab
@(n)mod(magic(n),n)+1
```