# Output a Latin square with a program which is a Latin square

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source, printable-ascii

A [Latin square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square) of order n is text which is arranged as a square of n lines by n columns, contains n different characters, and each character appears once in each line and column. For example, here is a Latin square of order 9:

```
Code gOlf
ode gOlfC
de gOlfCo
e gOlfCod
 gOlfCode
gOlfCode 
OlfCode g
lfCode gO
fCode gOl
```

Make a program which outputs a Latin square of order n (like in [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/223590/25315) other challenge), but the program must also be a Latin square of order n. The output must be different (i.e. not a quine) - use different symbols and/or in different order.

Some notes on formatting:

1. Output to stdout or return a string which could be printed to stdout directly (i.e. it should contain newline bytes).
2. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed only if the square doesn't otherwise contain spaces.
3. Leading and trailing newlines are allowed.
4. Tab and other control characters are allowed only if your system can print them without disturbing the square shape.
5. Usual Code Golf - your score is the number of bytes in your program, so a score should  normally be n²+n-1 or n²+n.
6. Include your program's output in your answer, if you think it looks pretty.

---

As noted by tsh, n = 1 is uninteresting, so let's add a restriction n > 1.

Comment: Won’t this question just encourage 1 byte answers like Retina or so? Had I missed anything in the question which prevent 1 byte answers?

Comment: I missed that possibility; I guess it's bad style to disallow that now, but I'll just go ahead and do that.

Comment: @anatolyg There are no answers yet, so I think you can still ban it.

Comment: Does a character need to appear exactly once in every line and column or the same number of times in each line or column?

Comment: Once in every column, once in every row. Also described in Wikipedia; see there if there is any doubt.

Comment: Newer .NET versions allow you to create executable programs without an EntryPoint or Main method. Without the n>1 restriction, which was a good suggestion, my F# submission would have been an empty file for 0 bytes.

Answer (score 15):

## C89 (using implicit `int`), 811 bytes (\$ n = 28 \$)

```c
ps0,f;to(char/*1+){2-u9]y=}[
+,}2=s09f-(put1;*/oy[]){char
u[9012]={f};/*c-as)rt(,op+hy
th,+p-;])0r}a92{s1([fc*/oy=u
;for(ps0/*t]9y=u,h1-}2[c{a)+
o1ayc{-}[]f+th,r)(u*/=29;ps0
-=1;u[ps0/*2)fa+hrc,9o}(]ty{
}c2)y9rtp;,[so+h-0fu{a(1*/]=
92-ps0+/*h1t;)o}{=yc(ru,a][f
s]+9a)1(}r-,[upy;f0=c{oht*/2
);for(/*1p9{]0[s2-}+a,=yhuct
]{(h[,ay+sp-}r)0ucto1*/f=29;
f-=1;oy[29/*ps(,t{+0)}]arcuh
au[=of,h;+{sc}y9(t2)p0r*/-1]
=oy[0])puts/*c;(92r1+-h}f{,a
29cf]a[{,u0rh-stp*/(oy+=1);}
/*r{th};-)=u,]920+pfy1a[so(c
,+s/h*{2]a;1=[0py9-trfc)u}o(
{t]u+c2)s1yo-,/[r}a9=hp0(;f*
1(*c{/u+a2])o=}f[,9shty;-0rp
y0t-/r(f={a9+1uoc][h*p;s},2)
*)ha9}fcy,u({+r=o[]p;/0-21ts
(/{]2yc-o}+hfpta=u*;s91r)[0,
cy)t*=91r[2f0a-]};h/,s{u+(po
[au*}+=rh(cy2{f)/o,]0;tp9s-1
0}/s,1hatyoc(;]*fp={u)-2[r+9
rp;()u*,co[=y2h/1as}]+ft09{-
hrp}-tou9=)01({c]y;a2[s+,f*/
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##HZFJqiUgDEXnrsQWm5mIKxEHIljWoEqxGUhw7e/7/jAhJ7mcZPEn58@/9Pc/JrAaJu5@@lS8uFfkmoakmhEwYtt4/A2I8Wv8VLYI3PfSjsp2QiTwnUU7WKVN9FCukzSLNMlYmLfO6kGrctaFi0SNm6yBqXEo@cv7jVxpA7/Dkq5oX4NXLa4JGRJhqOl0MogbYmFvyyB4U@mNdQ9Awmu3wy9qSEmsjsxtuziuA@hmQ44dqzseZmNVqLIhYU1l9Mga8TAmadXLkXbBn4zH5imGgmZkNhGN7xA87H5cUT5Dq4tKg8hv3KemW4gqTCMuS9yfuvNCEXANPB02u7iDqNdr72D5BkblG/cZM1bSPjFfwBS5MY28K0o7@FZ4dQxmvsfiZUhXg0qhI/KPUpE86fOpddiaoZmotwBPyNhcYgrAtxpVzNWpxO0wr98/kaQDVr1OkOc1WqNYL0enJwRnxNmUlYKJyWkfVD9WrFEy2bdhBCtu9hROfZrgMnwf52tX2BWKNKYZ5GbJRNL8LYHbWddxQo2OjlpCDlw8JMv0bjmGSrublxuCKKnJ3pIP3xjY8C3E7qQSRq@JsIRoThbtslr6Sn5TN60eJCiO8iGL@lcFU1QS8boq@YTNcG8opE0v86PifAwUIhuPyq1up9BIXTm5rmmdlrGLtHQPmwgTBrNodIfJpjy34I@pUqd5IytLWRCojn7Fatt6ojSGHI9LJkzGC5Wfzw8)

This is a function called `to` which prints the following output:

```
]\[ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCB
\[ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCB]
[ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCB]\
ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCB]\[
YXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCB]\[Z
XWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCB]\[ZY
WVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCB]\[ZYX
VUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCB]\[ZYXW
UTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCB]\[ZYXWV
TSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCB]\[ZYXWVU
SRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCB]\[ZYXWVUT
RQPONMLKJIHGFEDCB]\[ZYXWVUTS
QPONMLKJIHGFEDCB]\[ZYXWVUTSR
PONMLKJIHGFEDCB]\[ZYXWVUTSRQ
ONMLKJIHGFEDCB]\[ZYXWVUTSRQP
NMLKJIHGFEDCB]\[ZYXWVUTSRQPO
MLKJIHGFEDCB]\[ZYXWVUTSRQPON
LKJIHGFEDCB]\[ZYXWVUTSRQPONM
KJIHGFEDCB]\[ZYXWVUTSRQPONML
JIHGFEDCB]\[ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLK
IHGFEDCB]\[ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJ
HGFEDCB]\[ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJI
GFEDCB]\[ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIH
FEDCB]\[ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHG
EDCB]\[ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGF
DCB]\[ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFE
CB]\[ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFED
B]\[ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDC
```

I started with code like this:

```c
i;
to()
{
    char u[100] = {0};
    char *s = u;
    // Fill the string with some printable bytes
    for (i = 29; i -= 1; u[i] = 94 - i)
        ;
    for (i = 29; i -= 1; )
    {
        puts(s += 1); // print the string
        s[29 - 1] = s[0]; // rotate the string
    }
}
```

I arranged it as a sequence of strings which all have unique characters, padded with spaces in such a way that I could replace spaces with comments later. Then I tweaked the code repeatedly, until all columns also contained unique characters. This was not easy!

The result was this:

```c
ps0,f;to(char
                  oy[]){char
u[9012]={f};
                        oy=u
;for(ps0
                     =29;ps0
-=1;u[ps0
                          ]=
92-ps0+
                           2
);for(
                       f=29;
f-=1;oy[29
                         -1]
=oy[0])puts
                   (oy+=1);}
```

I had to use multi-character variable names to make all the string fragments have different lengths. I tried to use a minimal subset of characters, but ultimately I failed to satisfy all constraints and added an extra character `y`. So it seems possible to golf this further (if you want to do this — good luck, I'm out!)

Then, I made a script which completes any partially filled rectangle to a Latin square, randomizing characters inside the comments and doing backtracking.

Answer (score 12):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 109 bytes

Full program that prints to stdout.

```apl
(↑⍋⌽¨⊂) ⎕D
↑⍋⌽¨⊂) ⎕D(
⍋⌽¨⊂) ⎕D(↑
⌽¨⊂) ⎕D(↑⍋
¨⊂) ⎕D(↑⍋⌽
⊂) ⎕D(↑⍋⌽¨
) ⎕D(↑⍋⌽¨⊂
 ⎕D(↑⍋⌽¨⊂)
⎕D(↑⍋⌽¨⊂) 
D(↑⍋⌽¨⊂) ⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94L/Go7aJj3q7H/XsPbTiUVeTpsKjvqkuXNgENbgwhYDquDCFgOq4MIWA6riwiB1awYUpBFTHhU1QkwuboAKXCzZvgDz4vwAA)

`⎕D` the digits `0` through `9`

`(`…`)` apply the following tacit function:

`⊂` on the entire argument:

`⌽¨` rotate each of the following amounts:

`⍋` the grade (the permutation that would sort the argument, i.e. the indices 1 through 10)

`↑` mix the list of strings into a character matrix

The first rotation ends up having unbalanced parentheses and therefore quits with an error, causing no further output on stdout.

Answer (score 10):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), 11 bytes (\$ n = 3 \$)

```
drz
rzd
zdr
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuharU4qquIqqUriqUoogIlAJmAIA)

Reads its own source code and reverses it. (I can't see anything in the question which disallows this.)

##### Output

```
rdz
dzr
zrd
```

##### Explanation

Only the last line matters:

```python
zd   # Read source code and push to stack
  r  # Reverse so the output is different
     # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 8):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 239 bytes (n=15)

```
choue=:i.+|~/15
i=:15.|+/~choue
=echo|.u:i+/~51
51|i.+/~=:eouhc
15/.|~+:eui=coh
+.5|:1=cu/~iheo
|ih~/o51+c.:e=u
o|ie15~/c.hu+:=
~+15cuoh|e/.=i:
huec+/1o~5=|:.i
u/~=hci|o1:e5+.
/~.:=eu51hoci|+
:o+/~ihe5=u1.c|
.cu+i:e=ho15|/~
e:=ouhc.i|5+1~/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY4xikBBCEN7ryIoFjaCpxmEcRsrO/Hqf2e3CryEJD/fd251uCXhLItCuonSIO@/Ax5Ph9ryIRVQmZfldYvqe0CUaRYtOv3UBSQdEz/NmzcKJu9yqeAhC2@oyRBdPnQbzWFR9HTdCSZPg9txkKVWfYwSXo/fk1NioUjAS@bRKrceRbDC/yX1FjoDdBrzLd0SHV4I87@flKMoy9/3Cw)

---

### Explanation

```
choue=:i.+|~/15
```

- `|~/` is a no-op on 15: it inserts `|~` between the items, but there's only one item.
- `+` is complex conjugation, which is also a no-op on 15.
- `i.` makes a list of the first 15 nonnegative integers.
- That list is assigned to `choue`.

```
i=:15.|+/~choue
```

- `+/~` makes an addition table of the integers in `choue`.
- `15.` `|` reduces it modulo 15; the full stop is used as a decimal point.
- The result is assigned to `i`.

```
=echo|.u:i+/~51
```

- `+/~` here ends up being the same as plain addition, adding 51 to each item of `i`.
- `u:` converts numbers to characters.
- `|.` reverses the result. (Something had to be put here to separate `echo` from `u:`.)
- `echo` outputs the table of characters.
- `=` doesn't matter because it is applied after the `echo`.

```
51|i.+/~=:eouhc
```

- This line is a syntax error, ending execution.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 29 bytes

```
Rṙ`Y5
ṙ`Y5R
`Y5Rṙ
Y5Rṙ`
5Rṙ`Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/o4c6ZCZGmXBAqiAtEANlcECqBC0JF/v8PAA)

All lines but the last are ignored.

```
5R       [1 .. 5]
  ṙ      rotated left
   `     each of [1 .. 5] times.
    Y    Join on newlines.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 55 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) (\$ n = 7 \$)

```
0oā._»2
oā._»20
ā._»20o
._»20oā
_»20oā.
»20oā._
20oā._»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fIP9Io178od1GXDCGAReMkc8FpY80csEYelwwRjyXEUzz//8A)

##### Output

```
0485761
4857610
8576104
5761048
7610485
6104857
1048576
```

##### Explanation

We can ignore everything but the last line.

```python
20       # Push 20
  o      # Push 2 ** 20 (1048576)
   ā     # Push [1..7]
    ._   # Rotate 1048576 that many times
      »  # Join by newlines
         # Implicit output
```

Comment: It might be worth explaining why `6LD._»` inserts extra spaces for people who don't know the language. Very good answer, but it left me very confused!

Comment: @UnrelatedString I think that's because `6L` is a list, and so you will need to join each inner list after rotating. `1048576` is interpreted as a string and so it doesn't need joining (see [here](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fzMdFL/7/fwA))

Comment: [`7LD._J»` will work though](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f3MdFL97r0O7//wE)

Comment: My answer will remain deleted.. I've been unable to find a way to push 6 unique characters with 2 loose single-byte builtins, and with a single 2-byte builtin like `žO` you will get errors on the loose trailing `ž`. And although I did find a way to push a 5x5 Latin square with 5 characters ([`8zv=Á`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/foqrM9nDj//8A)), unfortunately it will print crap when expanding the source code to a Latin square.. (An alternative for `20o` could be `8z(`, though: [try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/SuNIo178od0WXDBGFReMocEFpY80csEYelwwRjyXBUzz//8A).)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen yeah, I tried `žO` just to see that it errors when it sees `ž\n` :(. Unfortunately `8z(` produces a square of side length 6, whereas we want side length 7 (to match the program).

Comment: @TheThonnu Ah, you're right. Either way, there isn't a way to get a 6x6 square from what I could find.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 41 bytes (\$ n = 6 \$)

```
∪:żvǓk
:żvǓk∪
żvǓk∪:
vǓk∪:ż
Ǔk∪:żv
k∪:żvǓ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJqIiwiIiwi4oiqOsW8dseTa1xuOsW8dseTa+KIqlxuxbx2x5Nr4oiqOlxudseTa+KIqjrFvFxux5Nr4oiqOsW8dlxua+KIqjrFvHbHkyIsIiIsIiJd)

##### Output

```
eiouya
iouyae
ouyaei
uyaeio
yaeiou
aeiouy
```

##### Explanation

Only the last line matters, so everything else can be ignored.

```python
k∪      # Push "aeiouy"
  :ż    # Duplicate and push [1..6]
    vǓ  # Rotate the string that many places
        # Implicit output, joined by newlines
```